# Flutter Login/Logout button Implementation

Tags: flutter

I have implemented Login and Logout button but not knowing how to show/hide button (List in Listview). Buttons are in Listview (inside drawer) and want to show button at top login and if user is logged in want to show Logout at end of Listview

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginandSignupScreen()));
              },
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).logout();

              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(flex: 2, child: Icon(Icons.card_travel)),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 widgets separately

```
loginButton(){
    return ();
}

logOutButton(){
    return ();
}
```

And then show them like this if the user is login in or logout

```
Padding(
    child: (isUserLogedIn) ? logOutButton() : loginButton()
)
```

The buttons can be like

```
loginButton(){
    return FlatButton(
        child: Text("Log in"), 
        onPressed: LogInFunction()
    );
}
```

Comment: isUserLogedIn ? how can i check based on shared preference..SharedPreferences _prefs =  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var userId = _prefs.getInt('userId');

Comment: Just set a boolean in sharedPreferences if you are logged in or not. I dont know if you are using some backend or something, but u need to know if the user is logged im and its email, name or something